# ant design - huge imports

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using [ant design library](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) for my react application.

And I've faced with huge imports, that hurts my bundle (currently 1.1 mb in minified version because of ant-design lib).

How can I differently import antd components through all my app?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Seems `antd` has some huge or non optimized modules.
Here the thing - only difference is import Datepicker module, and.. boom! + almost 2MB (in dev bundle ofc.)

[image]

Comment: I am using antd for a small project with only two route. The project size is 1.6MB after uglify. Kindly provide an answer here if you able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 23):

**UPD:** the underlying issue seems to be resolved for the new (4.0) version of antd.
Therefore, if you try to resolve this issue for the earlier versions, the recommended way is to migrate onto antd 4

**Previous answer:**

At the moment, a huge part of antd dist is SVG icons.
There is no official way to deal with it yet ([check the issue on github](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12011)).

But a [workaround](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12011#issuecomment-423173228) exists.

1. Adapt webpack to resolve icons differently. In your webpack config:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@ant-design/icons/lib/dist$": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/icons.js")
    }
  }
};
```

2. Create `icons.js` in the folder `src/` or wherever you want it. Be sure it matches the alias path!
   In this file, you define which icons antd should include.

```js
export {
  default as DownOutline
} from "@ant-design/icons/lib/outline/DownOutline";
```

It's also possible to do this with `react-app-rewired` (create-react-app modifications) within `config-overrides.js`

Comment: props to @Tobias Lins for this solution

Comment: how will this work on vite ?

Answer (score 12):

1) Prevent antd to load the all **moment localization**. 
Add webpack plugin and configure it in webpack.config.js like the follow:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /ru/),
],
resolve: {
    alias: {moment: `moment/moment.js`}
},
target: `web`
}
```

2) Use the **same moment version** as in antd library.

3) Use **modularized antd**
Use babel-plugin-import

```
// .babelrc or babel-loader option
{
  "plugins": [
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": "css" }]
    // `style: true` for less
  ]
}
```

I use **BundleAnalyzerPlugin** to analyze the bundle.

`plugins: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()]`

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the docs
https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started#Import-on-Demand
there is a recommedation to import individual components on demand.
So, you can try and replace

```
import { Button} from 'antd'
```

with

```
import Button from 'antd/lib/button'
```

Comment: This is automatically taken care of when using [babel-plugin-import](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import)

Comment: I found https://github.com/vazco/uniforms/issues/219 helpful.

Comment: @DaveHowson Yes but babel-plugin-import can be used with popular tools like create-react-app only by ejecting. Read [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2463) on GitHub for more info.

Comment: I tried this approach in `import { Collapse } from "antd/lib/collapse";` and destructuring `const { Panel } = Collapse;` but getting error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Panel' of 'antd_lib_collapse__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Collapse' as it is undefined.`

Comment: this definitely helped. even on 5.2.3 it was taking a long time to load.

Answer (score 6):

I reduced my bundle size by 500KB by editing `config-override.js` like so:

**config-override.js**

```js
const { override, fixBabelImports } = require('customize-cra');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: 'css'
  }),
  // used to minimise bundle size by 500KB
  function(config, env) {
    const alias = config.resolve.alias || {};
    alias['@ant-design/icons/lib/dist$'] = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/icons.js');
    config.resolve.alias = alias;
    return config;
  }
);
```

**./src/icons.js**

```js
/**
 * List all antd icons you want to use in your source code
 */
export {
  default as SearchOutline
} from '@ant-design/icons/lib/outline/SearchOutline';

export {
  default as CloseOutline
} from '@ant-design/icons/lib/outline/CloseOutline';

export {
  default as QuestionCircleOutline
} from '@ant-design/icons/lib/outline/QuestionCircleOutline';

export {
  default as PlayCircleOutline
} from '@ant-design/icons/lib/outline/PlayCircleOutline';

export {
  default as PauseCircleOutline
} from '@ant-design/icons/lib/outline/PauseCircleOutline';

export {
  default as LoadingOutline
} from '@ant-design/icons/lib/outline/LoadingOutline';
```

#### Before

[image: Screen Shot 2019-11-05 at 2 56 54 pm]

#### After

[image: Screen Shot 2019-11-05 at 2 56 48 pm]

Comment: Hi @Jan, How can we know which icons should we import in icons.js file. I have an InputNumber and also Select dropdown. but the arrows are not visible :-| Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Those few components are certainly not 1.2M together. Looks like you are importing the whole library when you only need a few components.

To get `antd` to load only the needed modules you should use [babel-plugin-import](https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started#Import-on-Demand). Check your console log for the "You are using a whole package of antd" warning described at that link.

Check out the [docs for Create-React-App](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app) for how to implement it if you're using CRA.

Comment: My console is clean as baby tear. And I'm already using babel-plugin-import. Anyway bundle still huge. Will try to reformat my imports with import Thing from 'antd/lib/thing'. It will reduce size, probably, but definitely will cause many import strings.

Comment: Well something is wrong with your setup. My bundles usually has all of the components you list except Layout, plus many more. antd is 348kB uncompressed. The **entire** app including antd, React and stupidly large lodash plus lots of other stuff is 350kB gzipped.

Comment: A tip: https://github.com/chrisbateman/webpack-visualizer is a simple plugin that will give you a very good visual report of your bundle where you can drill down inside of modules. You can use it to see which parts of Antd are actually included.

Comment: Had the same problem as WebArtisan. Followed the instructions for CRA step by step. It didn't help the bundle still contains components that I don't use. Here are screenshots of my package.json. config-overrides.js, and the visualisation of bundle.js:

https://imgur.com/a/Pnpm4I3

Answer (score 0):

Try using [code splitting](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-code-splitting/) using webpack and react router. It will help you to load the modules asynchronously. This is the only solution helped me to improve the page load time when using ant framework.

Comment: I am also thinking of using react-loadable for async loading with antd but the Ant documentation talks about using react-app-rewire for modular imports. I am wondering if I should do both or just react-loadble for dynamic component import. I feel like code splitting alone should help but this thread worries me - https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12011

Answer (score 0):

[Issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12011) which caused large bundle size has been fixed in Ant Design 4.0.

Quoting from the [release announcement](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/20661#issue-545238682).

> **Smaller size**
>
> In antd @ 3.9.0, we introduced the svg icon ([Why use the svg icon?]
>   ()). The icon API
>   using the string name cannot be loaded on demand, so the svg icon file
>   is fully introduced, which greatly increases the size of the packaged
>   product. In 4.0, we adjusted the icon usage API to support tree
>   shaking, reducing the default package size of Antant by about 150 KB
>   (Gzipped).

In order to install Ant Design 4 you have to do following

```
npm install antd@4.0.0-rc.1
// or  in yarn
yarn add antd@4.0.0-rc.1
```