# Antd 2.7 mb budle size when i use only 3 components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

So i decided to use react, and antd on top of it. thought would be kinda cool. I am packing everything with webpack and my bundle size is about 2.8 megabytes Carl!

Even if i import a tiny checkbox from antd it is still the same bundle size. It imports whole antd in to a project. my assumption is that it shouldn't do it.

i used babel-import-plugin and it did reduce bundle size to 2.3 megabytes but in real world it is still not acceptable.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Checkbox} from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.less';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <h1>Hello React</h1>
        )
    }
}

function trig(){
    console.log("Changed");
}

ReactDOM.render(<Checkbox onChange={trig}>Click Me</Checkbox>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

So just to make this it takes 2.3 megabytes of code ?

.babelrc

```
{
    "plugins": [
        ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": true }]
        // `style: true` for less
      ]
  }
```

Update, With no antd my react bundle is only 118kb

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721290/ant-design-huge-imports

Comment: 2nd guess: antd is huge, but not SO huge. Are you sure you turned on minification?

Comment: @DaydreamingDuck i tried the methods in that post already, have the plugin installed but it still includes the whole thing. Second, yes i have minimization on.

Answer (score 4):

Good news is that you don't need any plugins or complicated webpack plugins / loaders / magic. All you have to do is to import directly from components folder!

**so instead of doing this**

```
import Checkbox from 'antd';
```

Or

```
import { Checkbox } from 'antd';
```

**You had to specify a single component location!**

```
import Checkbox from 'antd/es/checkbox';
```

Few things to note here, to further shrink that down you need the following things:

1) Use babel plugin called 'import' it helps a lot. `npm install babel-plugin-import`

2) Use webpack optimization! `optimization: {minimize: true}`

So now Carl instead of having 2.8 megabytes sitting in your bundle, you have only 221kb for your users to download. and remember to use compression when you serve your bundles.